# Shiny App - take user input into user defined function and download resulting files

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build my first Shiny app.

I have a user defined function which takes generates encryption keys. I'd like to make it in to a Shiny app.

I had a go as below.
The first bit of the UI works in that it asks for text input for the users name (this should be used to label the output files) - and I managed to get an action button which the user could then click to in theory run the code to make the encryption keys.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for ODK Encryption app ----

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Make ODK Encryption Keys"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("name",
                  "Enter your name:"),
      actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Generate Keys")

    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)
```

I feel that there ?should be something in mainPanel to give a link for the outputted key files or alternatively they could just automatically get downloaded?

Then within the server section I 
1) Take the sys-date-time as a seed
2) Take the name (as inputted above) and link that to the sys-date to make a file name for the eventual keys
3) Then I define my function (create.key.pair) 
- This takes the sys-date-time (set in 1 above) and uses that and openSSL to generate a public and private key. It labels these files using the name inputted in point 2 (which should take the input from the sidebar section of the UI in the shiny app)

```
#Make the Key

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    key_seed <- round(as.numeric(Sys.time()),0)
    key_name <- paste(name,Sys.Date(),sep="_")
    create.key.pair<-function(keynumber)
    {
      folder<-paste("ODK.KEY",key_name,sep=".")                      #make a folder name
      system(paste("mkdir",folder,sep=" "))                           #create the folder

      name.private.key<-paste("ODK.PRIVATE.KEY.",key_name,".pem",sep = "") #make a name for the keys
      name.public.key<-paste("ODK.PUBLIC.KEY.",key_name,".pem",sep = "")

      keygen.private<-paste("openssl genrsa -out ",folder,"/",name.private.key," 2048",sep="") #create the system call
      system(command = keygen.private) #create the private key

      keygen.public<-paste("openssl rsa -in ",folder,"/",name.private.key," -inform PEM -out ",folder,"/",name.public.key," -outform PEM -pubout",sep="")

      system(command = keygen.public) #create the private key
    }
    create.key.pair(key_seed)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I need some guidance on whether
A) I need to add something within mainPanel to show/download the outputted files
B) The code within the server section should work

I can't currently tell if my error is in A or B just that it doesnt generate keys (whereas my R script version of this works just fine)

First time using Shiny so any help gratefully accepted.

Comment: There are some issues with calling input on the server site in your code: input$input_action instead of input$button and input$name instead of name. First change this and then you can start debugging the rest

Comment: The function also does not work correct. `key_name` is not specified as parameter

Answer (score 1):

If I fix some slight bugs it's working the same way in shiny and as a usual R script:

1. `input$input_action` and `input$name`
2. adding `key_name` to your function

Also, do not load your function in `observeEvent` as this will cause your app to reload the function every time someone clicks the `actionButton`. You can instead load it once prior to your app start.

Your code is then:

```r
library(shiny)

create.key.pair<-function(keynumber, key_name)
{
    folder<-paste("ODK.KEY",key_name,sep=".")                      #make a folder name
    system(paste("mkdir",folder,sep=" "))                           #create the folder

    name.private.key<-paste("ODK.PRIVATE.KEY.",key_name,".pem",sep = "") #make a name for the keys
    name.public.key<-paste("ODK.PUBLIC.KEY.",key_name,".pem",sep = "")

    keygen.private<-paste("openssl genrsa -out ",folder,"/",name.private.key," 2048",sep="") #create the system call
    system(command = keygen.private) #create the private key

    keygen.public<-paste("openssl rsa -in ",folder,"/",name.private.key," -inform PEM -out ",folder,"/",name.public.key," -outform PEM -pubout",sep="")

    system(command = keygen.public) #create the private key
}

# Define UI for ODK Encryption app ----

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Make ODK Encryption Keys"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("name",
                      "Enter your name:"),
            actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Generate Keys")

        ),

        mainPanel(

        )
    )
)

#Make the Key

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$input_action, {

        key_seed <- round(as.numeric(Sys.time()),0)
        key_name <- paste(input$name,Sys.Date(),sep="_")
        create.key.pair(key_seed, key_name)
    })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This works in the sense that it generates the keys in the background - I feel like I then need to use ?downloadhandler to allow the user to generate each file? With two separate download buttons one for each file as I understand zipping is not easy?

Comment: Adding a `downloadButton` is easy, you only need to replace `actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Generate Keys")` by `downloadButton("input_action", label = "Generate Keys")`. Then, you need to specify the `downloadHandler` in `observeEvent`. For this, you need to rewrite your function to directly pass the generated file to it. Therefore, it should not be directly saved to your directory.

Comment: For an example of the shiny `downloadButton` have a look at the official RStudio description: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.4/downloadButton.html